# Testing model method in a Rspec controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I would like to test a model method from my controller. I am trying the following (simplified code):

model.rb

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def configure(threshold)
    self.some_private_method(threshold)   ## threshold is an int
  end
end
```

models_controller.rb

```
def edit
   case params.require(:threshold_string)
   when 'low'
      model.configure(1)
   end
end
```

model_controller_spec.rb

```
RSpec.describe ModelsController, type: :controller do
  describe 'PUT configure' do
    let(model) {create :model}
    let(:subject) { put :configure, threshold_string: 'low' }
    it 'should receive a 1' do
      model = spy('model')
      subject
      expect(model).to have_received(:configure)
    end
  end
end
```

Error message when I run the test

```
Failure/Error: expect(model).to have_received(:configure)
(#<Model:0x000000065ac0c0>).configure(*(any args))
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 0 times with any arguments
```

Any thoughts on why spy doesn't work? I have also tried calling `allow(model).to receive(:configure)` and then call subject (and reverse the order). Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, it seems that you want to whitelist your `threshold_string` param. You can do that with `params.permit(:threshold_string)`. However this returns a hash like `{"threshold_string"=>"low"}` which doesn't match any case in your `case` statement. So 2 things:

1. In your controller, do `case params[:threshold_string]`
2. In your spec, pass the correct param: `put :configure, threshold_string: 'low'`

Comment: Hey Jan - Thank you for your corrections. I didn't paste the actual code because it would become too long and I made mistakes in the process. I'll update it with your corrections and include the error message. Hope that helps answer my question.

Comment: Given that your code is already updated, you'll need to change your controller line `case params.require(:threshold_string)` to `case params[:threshold_string]`. Try to put a `puts` statement inside `when 'low'` case for debugging and you'll see it's not reached.